# Appcelerator - Email Dialog Attaches Signature in Text File

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

If I create an email dialog using the following code and send it from my iPhone, my signature text (even if blank) is attached as a separate text file.  How can I prevent this from happening?

```
var email = Titanium.UI.createEmailDialog();
email.subject = 'My Subject';
email.toRecipients = ['you@there.com'];
email.messageBody = 'Body message.';
var file = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile('attachment.pdf');
email.addAttachment(file);
email.open();
```

Comment: Does this also happen without the attachment?

Comment: No.  If I don't attach a file, I don't get the additional signature attachment.  Are you able to reproduce this behavior?

Comment: It looks like you've found a bug then. Thanks for that! Could you check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, please create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.